# Oracle SQL Developer - Unable to run queries using varchar field as identifier

Tags: sql, database, oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper

I'm new to using Oracle SQL Developer and to using an Oracle DB (have mainly used MySQL before)

I'm trying to do something like:

```
select * from content_definition where content_id = "hhhh233";
```

Where `content_id` is:

```
VARCHAR2(1000 BYTE)
```

But am getting:

```
ORA-00904: "hhhh233": invalid identifier
00904. 00000 -  "%s: invalid identifier"
*Cause:    
*Action:
Error at Line: 1 Column: 52
```

I'm not really understanding why this isn't working as I used to do queries like this all the time with MySQL. I have been searching on this but nothing seems to be for my specific use case. I would appreciate if anyone can set me in the right direction on this. Thanks

Comment: You query works in MySQL because MySQL ignores a lot of the SQL standards for naming (and quoting) objects (at least in the default installation)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to use single quotes for character data; double quotes signify identifiers and aliases:

```
select * from content_definition where content_id = 'hhhh233';
```

Answer (score 3):

String delimiter in Oracle is a single quote ('), like this:

```
select * from content_definition where content_id = 'hhhh233';
```

Double quotes are only used for identifiers (e.g. column names and tables).